# Invoking a C callback, received through SWIG, from Java code

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, function-pointers, swig

I am using SWIG to generate Java and C++ wrappers to connect Java and C code: Java code ↔ C++ wrapper code ↔ C code.

1. C structure is defined like below, with a callback function pointer:

   ```c
   BOOL (STDCALL *sendAsyncRequest)(http_req_params *params, http_req **req);

   typedef struct http_req_params
   {
       CHAR*                url;
       struct
       {
           UCHAR          name[100];
           UCHAR          val[100];
       } hdrs[10];
       plt_http_responseCB    rspCallBack;
       plt_http_type_params           *http_type_params;
       plt_http_req_multipart_info    *multipartReqData;
   } _plt_http_req_params;

   typedef struct {
       UINT32                           length;
       VOID                             *pMultipartContent;
       CHAR                             contentType[10];
   } http_req_multipart_contents;

   typedef struct {
       CHAR                             multipartBoundaryInfo[10];
       UINT32                           multipartContentCount;
       http_req_multipart_contents         **multipartContents;
   } plt_http_req_multipart_info;
   ```
2. Now I want to wrap the above struct in a Java object using SWIG. How do we register for the callback function (`plt_http_responseCB`) with Java layer?
3. This is the response callback definition:

   ```c
   typedef BOOL (STDCALL *plt_http_responseCB)(plt_http_rsp_params *rspInfo);

   typedef struct _plt_http_rsp_params
   {
       UINT16 reqStatus;
       UINT16 httpStatus;
       VOID * userData;
       plt_buf_info rspData;
       struct
       {
           UCHAR   name[100];
           UCHAR   val[100];
       } hdrs[10];
   } plt_http_rsp_params;
   ```

On some OS events, we need to notify the C layer with the callback function (`plt_http_responseCB`) which we received as part of C struct.

How can I achieve this using SWIG and generate Java wrappers?  How can I apply the ["director" feature](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors_faq) in this use case?

Comment: So what is it that you want to accomplish? I have a hard time extracting any meaning out of this Time Cube aesthetic.

Comment: The C function pointer will come as parameter to java. I  want to call C function pointer back from java. need to generate wrappers accordingly. http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors_faq

Comment: Directors is a C++ feature. Do you want to do this using only C?

Comment: Want to use in SWIG as a tool.

Comment: just some voice in my head: 1) Save a callback pointer address as a long value 2) Pass it up to java 3) Create a simple native java method with the needed arguments + the long argument for a pointer 4) On the OS event call that native function 5) Handle that call on JNI(native) layer and cast the pointer(void*) to plt_http_responseCB 6) Invoke the callback passing the arguments that came along