# Send hashmap object from c JNI to Java

Tags: java, android, c, hashmap, java-native-interface

Want to pass hashmap data from C JNI to java. Planning to take java instance of my MyJavaHolderClass class and set the hashmap object and other variables. is this right way?

```
public class MyJavaHolderClass {

    HashMap<String,String> headersMap  = null;
    String  url;

    public HashMap<String, String> getHeadersMap() {
        return headersMap;
    }

    public void setHeadersMap(HashMap<String, String> headersMap) {
        this.headersMap = headersMap;
    }
     public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

1. get the instance of MyJavaHolderClass at JNI.
2. Set the methods(setUrl, setHeadersMap) of MyJavaHolderClass.
3. From jni call java sendReqeuest(jobject)//jobject is MyJavaHolderClass.
4. Java class method will look like public void sendReqeuest(MyJavaHolderClass myJavaHolderClass)
5. myJavaHolderClass.getUrl  myJavaHolderClass.getHeadersMap should give values set at #2.

How to achieve #2 from JNI level?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Set the methods"_? In any case, the signature for `setHeadersMap` ought to be something like `"(Ljava/util/HashMap;)V"`.

Comment: Set values actually here in this case 1 takes string and other takes hashmap as parameter.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're talking about. In case you're referring to overloaded Java methods, then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814563/jni-native-function-overload-signature as well as the Oracle documentation that the question links to.

Comment: i need to send hashmap data from C JNI to java class(Method which takes hashmap as input params).
https://gist.github.com/theeasiestway/e5f453715cecc55b5ca57d0628b9f12a

Comment: But what is the question? I can't decipher from what you've written so far exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628532/invoking-a-c-callback-received-through-swig-from-java-code
sendAsyncRequest method will be called from C layer, need to pass the struct data(Hashmap) from JNI to java .